# Por que o id é ambiguo mesmo criando um alias?

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join

```
select deals.id as dealid from funnels
inner join deals on 
deals.funnel_id = funnels.id where id = 3
```

retorna

## 1052 - Coluna 'id' em 'where clause' é ambígua

Meu banco de dados é o MySQL. Por que houve ambiguidade sendo que eu criei um apelido para o deals.id?

Comment: Sem você mostrar as estruturas das tabelas deals e funnels só poderíamos especular e não responder claramente. Talvez seja este final ...where id = 3.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O erro já diz a origem, que é `em 'where clause'`. O alias, não muda nada nesse caso, já que o `WHERE` permanece como `id = 3`. *Você fez certo no `select` e errado no `where`.*

A solução, mesmo sem alias, seria usar:

```
select deals.id from funnels
inner join deals on 
deals.funnel_id = funnels.id where deals.id = 3
```

Claro, como é ambíguo, estou considerando que esteja se referindo ao `deals.id = 3`, se não for isso, será `funnels.id = 3`. Enfim, o problema é no `WHERE`, como o erro aponta, então é só fazer o mesmo que fez no `select`, especificar qual tabela *quer usar* (`tabela.id`).